# ListBox with ItemsSource of List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: wpf

I'm setting the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox` to the `values` of a `ValueSet` instance. Here is `ValueSet`:

```
public class ValueSet
{
    public string valuetype;
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> values;
    public double count;
}
```

Of course, the `ListBox` displays each item as "(Collection)" (list box on the right):

[image]

Each `Dictionary<string,object>` element in `values` is expected to have a pair with a key of `text`. I'd like for the `ListBox` to display the value of this pair. Can this be done by setting the `DisplayMemberPath` of the `ListBox`? If so what should it be set to? If not, what's a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least you should be able to bind using the indexer syntax for binding "[text]".  Use the ItemTemplate of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[text]}" />
```

You could also instead try setting `DisplayMemberPath="[text]"`, but I have no idea whether that would work.

Comment: Thanks McGarnagle! `DisplayMemberPath="[text]"` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Using DisplayMemberPath we can able to achieve this by setting the Binding as Value. Please follow the below code snippet.

DisplayMemberPath="Value"